# How can I best replace an svg font-based graphic with a png

Tags: css

I am adapting an open source project, our fork is a little different than and I need to switch around some of the hard-coded graphics and wording.

At the top of the footer file (writen in haml) there is this

```
.footer
    .footer-top

        %p.by-line Brought to you by #{@city.brought_by}, in partnership with the people of #{@city.name}. <a href="http://#{@city.agency_url}">#{@city.agency_url}</a>
```

And in the corresponding html file there is this:

```
 .by-line:before {

   font-family: 'collier72-icons'; 
   font-size: 2.7rem;
   content: 'y';
   color: $mid-grey;
   position: absolute;
   left: -6.5rem;
   bottom: 0.1rem;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}
```

The result ends up looking like this:
[image]

Looks great, right? ...but I want to change it to look like this mockup I created:

[image]

So, I need to change the layout but I don't know how to change the haml file. If it were html I'd add a div with a background image.. or even just an inline image ...but I've fallen in haml land and I can't get up.

Comment: ps - if you are curious, this is based on code that is in github at github.com/city72/city-72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `content` property and adjust from there.

```
.by-line:before {
  font-family: 'collier72-icons'; 
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  content: url("path/to/file.png");
  color: $mid-grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: -6.5rem;
  bottom: 0.1rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Awesome :D happy times~

Comment: .by-line:before {
  content: url("/assets/static/cc_logo.png");
  position: absolute;
  display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 169px; 
   height: 66px; 
   left: -11rem;
        bottom: -.2rem;
        }

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to make the image responsive, you can use a background image & set the background to be responsive.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pohuski/x0d4v80y/1/

```
.by-line:before {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  width: 100%; /* width of image */
  max-width: 300px; /* width of image */
  height: 150px; /* height of image */
  background: url(path/to/image.png) no-repeat fixed center; /* image path */
  position: absolute;
  left: -6.5rem;
  bottom: 0.1rem;
}
```

Comment: hmmm.. I couldn't get it to work, but I think it might have something to do with the way images are referenced in my app. I'll give it a shot again tomorrow (it's too late to be up front-end coding (for me)). Thanks again!